# Export the secret key without the export file being passphrase-encrypted

Tags: gnupg

I have a secret key encrypted with a passphrase. Take this:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys --armor KEYID >backupfile.asc
```

This does its job without asking me for a passphrase. I conclude, therefore, that it saves the secret key encrypted with the passphrase. What I want, however, is for it to unencrypt the secret key and then back it up unencrypted. How can I do this?

Comment: Is your GPG version less than 2.1.0? Until then you could do `gpg --export-secret-keys --armor --export-options export-reset-subkey-passwd`

Comment: @Bandrami Thanks, I have 1.4.18. But apparently this only resets the subkey password, not the main key, does it? And anyway, I am reluctant to use deprecated functionality.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

The required patch would be quite trivial to the GnuPG, however, its development upstream likely won't do it. However, the GnuPG is opensource software, a project fork on the github (including the fix of a lot of other major usability problems, unneeded features and so on) would be likely a warmly welcomed one.

This is the typical case as the upstream development mixes the terminology of "security" with "unusability".